# localization using database

Tags: android, localization, android-sqlite

I need to localize my application.i have done it by populating the strings in various strings.xml under values-en,value-es etc.
Now i want to do it through database.I found out that we cannot change the strings.xml on runtime.Can you tell you me how to do the localization with database

Till now i created a table and was writing it in a xml file(using DOM) ...like strings.xml.

could write the strings.xml in  console but not in the strings.xml file..

now i am totally confused...

Please guide me how to implement localization using  sqlite....i am done with construction of tables ...

how to pass them to resources on the fly....
Please please please help  and please provide and example

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work, can you not simply restart the app if you want to change locale? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181847/android-change-the-locale-at-runtime

Comment: I am near sure, google will be not list your app as multilanguage, if you will use other method of translation than xml files.

Comment: `Now i want to do it through database.` Altough you **could** do so, it's not the preferred way to.