# Android: How do i avoid duplicate resource files for different product flavours?

Tags: android, xml, duplicates, android-productflavors

In My Application I have two product flavours, flavour1 and flavour2.

I also have language Files for 4 Languages: German, English, French and Spanish

My problem is:

- In **flavour1** the default language is ***German***
- In **flavour2** the default language is ***English***

My current solution is:
I put the German `strings.xml` in

```
flavour1/res/values/strings.xml
flavour2/res/values-de/strings.xml
```

And the English files in

```
flavour1/res/values-en/strings.xml
flavour2/res/values/strings.xml
```

So I have both files twice in my project.

how can I solve this so that I have each file only once in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the default language during "onCreate" you do not need to have a flavour for that please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181847/change-the-locale-at-runtime) to understand how to do that

Comment: unfortunately i cheered to soon.. it seems to work on the first glance, but now i get many crashes where some ressource files are not found, because they are not present in the default values folder.