# Android: localization works for all but one activity

Tags: android, locals

Problem looks like that. In my app I have 3 activities (so far, fourth is comming). One of them is settings screen where user can choose his language. When settings are changed I update activities and now magic comes... all activities change their language except one - main menu activity.
No matter what I do it works for all activities but this one.
Funny thing is that I've checked and method to update locals is done and also proper language setting is used.

Main activity code (I've removed code that doesn't matter in this case):

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Preferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    initialize();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    applySettings();
    super.onResume();
}

private void initialize() {
    preferences = Preferences.getInstance();
    preferences.initiate(this);
}

private void applySettings() {
    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Activity.setLocale(getApplicationContext(), preferences.getLanguage().getValue());
}
```

}

Here's method that sets locals:

```
public class ActivitySettings {

public static void setLocale(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

As you see I've added line to show current language before update, and it show that language is correct.
Why it won't change language for main activity?!

---

### EDIT - found a solution

I've added new variable in my main activity

```
private Locale currentLocal = null;
```

Then on initiation I set this to current locale

```
currentLocal = Locale.getDefault();
```

Now in onResume() I've added that

```
if (currentLocal.getLanguage() != Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()) {
        currentLocal = Locale.getDefault();
        recreate();
    }
```

Now it works perfect.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181847/change-the-locale-at-runtime?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Although question you directed me to was not strictly about my problem, but it gave me a hint and now it works! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At first download this Helper class from [here](https://gist.github.com/sshuvro58/739c11314a2840793eb739e45f0abb84)  , now copy `LocaleHelper.java` into your project . After that create a class which will extent `Application`  , now in the `onCreate` of your application put this `LocaleHelper.onCreate(getApplicationContext())`

**Example**

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        initializeConfigurations(getApplicationContext());
        LocaleHelper.onCreate(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Don't forget to mention it in manifest file

```
<application
    android:name=".SampleApplication"
    ...........................
```

Now you can set your Locale from anywhere in the app like this   `LocaleHelper.setLocale(context,"fr")` , in this example I just set the Locale to `french` which will effect all activities .

Comment: Check my code I've pasted above. I did that exactly as you did, and it was working for all but one activity, main activity.

Comment: where did you paste it ?