# How can I set the device language as my app language by default in the Android?

Tags: android

i.e. If a device is running in a particular language (Say Spanish) then how can I set the Spanish language(After translation) as the default language of the app without asking the user.

The app should initialize in the Spanish language in this case while installation and a user should be able to change the language from the setting page of the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language programmatically in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: It already is the default language.

Comment: also a possible duplicate of [Stackoverflow change-the-locale-at-runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181847/change-the-locale-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all `string.xml` files in specific language values folder.
So when your user change mobile default language your app may take string values from that particular language values `strings.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

By Locale, you can get a currently selected language of a device. Please have a look below code to get the language.

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```