# programmatically changing app language and maintain language with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to change the app language programmatically when language name is clicked on in the navigation drawer list. The language changes but I am not able to maintain when the app is closed.
here my `setLocal` method

```
private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(MY_LANG,lang);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

I call this method when I want to change the lang like this

```
              if (id == R.id.ar_lang){
                    setLocale("ar");
                    recreate();
                }
                if (id == R.id.eng_lang){
                    setLocale("en");
                    recreate();
                }
```

and I call this method in onCreate to get the stored language, but it doesn't work.

```
public void loadLocale(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String languages =  prefs.getString(MY_LANG,"");
        setLocale(languages);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675427/519334 to change app language at runtime.

> and I call this method in onCreate to get the stored language, but it doesn't work.

my solution ony works if languagesetup is done (`loadLocale()`)  **before** super.OnCreate() is called

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    loadLocale();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ... initialize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass context with new configuration to your activity

Use this [LocaleHelper](https://gist.github.com/agarasul/5bf58b5e7cf66f7d70203bf9dc15f439) (written in Kotlin, but you do it by yourself in Java also)

Then in your activity call this method

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase!!))
}

override fun applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration: Configuration?) 
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP 
          && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        // update overrideConfiguration with your locale
        overrideConfiguration?.setLocale(LocaleHelper.getCurrentLocale(this))
        overrideConfiguration?.setLayoutDirection(LocaleHelper.getCurrentLocale(this))
    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
}
```